# How to scrape a table with BeautifulSoup [Python]

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

community,

I would like to deal with web scraping just for my own interest. The topic is very exciting and you can certainly gain a lot of interesting insights with the data available on the net.

In my first project I would like to generate some football data. For example, you can find information about previous injuries on [Transfermarkt Leroy Sane](https://www.transfermarkt.de/havard-nordtveit/verletzungen/spieler/192565).

**Goal:**
To scrape the whole table.

**Current status:**
I've managed to read out the Injuries column. Unfortunately I also get data from the "Missed matches" column.

**Question:**
Is there a better way to get the exact values from each column? Or is there even a better way to scrape whole tables?

Code:

```
import requests
import csv
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.transfermarkt.de/havard-nordtveit/verletzungen/spieler/192565"
heads = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=heads)
html_icerigi = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_icerigi, "html.parser")
injuries = soup.find_all(class_="hauptlink")
injuries_list = []
for injury in injuries:
        injuries_list.append(injury.text)
print(injuries_list)
```

I am still at the beginning, you are the professionals. I am looking forward to learning.

Thanks, if you invest time to help me.

Comment: For scrapping tables, it would be better to use ``pandas read_html``

Comment: Hi. In my initial research, I couldn't find a way to put a "user-agent" header in pandas. Therefore I start with BeautifulSoup. Did I miss something?

Comment: no you didn't miss anything (that i am aware of), but what you could do is use `requests` with the user-agent to get the html, then feed that into panads. see my solution below

Answer (score 0):

The cells of the column you're interested in look like this: `<td class="hauptlink">`. However, the cells of the last column (missed games) are: `<td class="rechts hauptlink wappen_verletzung">`.
Your query will capture these unwanted cells because technically their class matches the one you're looking for, when what you really wanted was all `td` tags whose class match exactly `hauptlink`.

You can make your tag query more specific with a CSS selector that deliberately only looks for `td` tags whose class is exactly `hauptlink`:

```
def main():

    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    url = "https://www.transfermarkt.de/havard-nordtveit/verletzungen/spieler/192565"

    headers = {
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0"
    }

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    response.raise_for_status()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

    for td in soup.select("td[class='hauptlink']"):
        print(td.text)

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Also, if you want to just capture the text from the tags in a list, you could do something like this, which is a bit cuter than appending to a list in a loop:

```
second_column = list(map(lambda tag: tag.text, soup.select("td[class='hauptlink']")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the table parsed with pandas (it uses beautifulsoup under the hood). `.read_html()` doesnt have to be a direct URL.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.transfermarkt.de/havard-nordtveit/verletzungen/spieler/192565"
heads = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=heads)

# Instead of feeding into beautifulsoup to parse the table tags yourself,
# feed the html into pandas to do that for you 
df = pd.read_html(response.text)[0]
```

**Output:**

```
print(df.to_string())
  Saison              Verletzung         von         bis      Tage Verpasste Spiele
0  19/20           Kreuzbandriss  05.08.2019  08.03.2020  216 Tage               44
1  17/18              Bänderriss  29.01.2018  11.02.2018   13 Tage                3
2  17/18               Erkältung  28.11.2017  01.12.2017    3 Tage                1
3  16/17                Nasen-OP  23.05.2017  02.07.2017   40 Tage                -
4  16/17        Muskelverletzung  18.12.2016  13.01.2017   26 Tage                5
5  16/17  Oberschenkelverletzung  04.08.2016  04.09.2016   31 Tage                5
6  15/16          Handverletzung  07.09.2015  10.09.2015    3 Tage                -
7  14/15        kleinere Blessur  20.04.2015  23.04.2015    3 Tage                -
8  14/15        Muskelverletzung  14.07.2014  28.08.2014   45 Tage                4
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code to get all tables in your html file:

```
tables = soup.select('table', attrs={"class":"hauptlink"})
```

and get every table with its own index like:

```
my_table = tables[index]
```

and get tr tags like:

```
rows = my_table.findChildren(['tr'])
```

and print table's cells like:

```
for row in rows:
     cells = row.findChildren('td')
     print (  cells[1].text ... )
```